# make lcov only capture part of codes (based on last N commits)

Tags: c, linux, gcov, lcov

I can use gcov/lcov/genhtml to generate test coverage report for `all the files`, now I want to only get the report for the last 10 commits.  how can I get there?

What I have tried is:

```
1. compile and run the program. 
2. lcov --directory . --capture --output-file redis.info
3. git diff HEAD~10..HEAD >  my.patch
4. lcov --diff ./redis.info my.patch -o redis-patch.info
```

I want to the the coverage for my.patch only but failed (looks coverage for all the data still)

Comment: generally lcov --diff is not designed for this purpose.   I will give an update once I got a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately lcov --diff is about patching sources in case coverage was generated but sources are old.
Few days ago [fastcov](https://github.com/RPGillespie6/fastcov) received ability in this [PR](https://github.com/RPGillespie6/fastcov/pull/56) to filter coverage using diff file. It is still not in release, but can be used and one-file tool. Tool is designed for GCC 9+, but you can safely run it with any GCC version if you want only to filter ready lcov's .info file. Usage will be next:

```
1. compile and run the program. 
2. lcov --directory . --capture --output-file redis.info
3. git diff HEAD~10..HEAD >  my.patch
4. python fastcov.py -C ./redis.info --diff-filter my.patch --lcov -o redis-patch.info
```